# Django jquery get content of button

Tags: jquery, django, button

I am working on a calendar where some dates are full and others are open.
All dates are dislayed with buttons but the Open-Date-Buttons open a form to create a new event on that date whereas the Full-Date-Buttons dont do anything. To open the form i am using a modal (the code for that is pretty mach copy pasted from bootstrap).

I am using a for loop in the template to create all the buttons. Whenever a Open-Date-Button is clicked i need to pass the forloop.counter to my function. Because the buttons are numbered with the forloop.counter i can just extract the content of the clicked button.
I already managed to pass other variables with jquery like this:

```
            var test = '{{empty}}'
```

But i fail to pass the forloop.counter

My html looks like this:

```
           {% for days, active in zip %}
    {% if active %}
    <button id="count" type="button" class="daybutton daybutton1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{forloop.counter}}">{{forloop.counter}}</button><!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{forloop.counter}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel{{forloop.counter}}">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Wählen Sie eine Uhrzeit für Ihren Termin am</h4><h5>{{ forloop.counter }}</h5><h6> {{month}} {{year}}</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              {{forloop.counter}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
              <button id="submit_btn" class="btn btn-link">Send the invitation</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    {% else %}
      <button id="inactive" class="daybutton inactive" > {{ forloop.counter}} </button>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

My script contains this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit_btn", function(event){
  count = $("#count").clone().html()
   alert(count)
  });
```

This displays an alert but the message is always "1".

I googled around a bit and tried different approaches but its always either 1, undefined or the last number of the forloop (in my case 29).

I would be glad for every help! =)

Comment: Well that is logical: the HTML is rendered at the server. So when the `<script>` is rendered, the `forloop.counter` is simply the value of the counter at that specific moment, typically the last value of the loop.

Comment: Yea that occured to me too when i recieved 29 so i displayed the counter in the modal title with the id = count 

`<h5 id="count">{{ forloop.counter }}</h5>`

I should be able to pull the rendered number out of the html but for some reason its always 1 :/

Comment: You have created an ID inside a for loop, `<button id="count">` this means multiple button wil be created with that same ID. obviously `js` will always  return the first ID when you do `count = $("#count").clone().html()`

Comment: Oh man i thought because i create a different modal for every button it could differ - it works when i use`id="submit_btn{{forloop.counter}}"` for my buttons (which i had tried before) and `id="count{{forloop.counter}}"``

Thanks a lot! =)

Comment: Ok I already posted an answer, it works, but not the best way to do it, i wonder how you will trigger it in js, check my answer, I am editing the way to do it

Comment: Well i want to pass the id to my views.py so that the form can display valid choices. I usually return a HttpResponse and use ` $('#changing_div').html(data)` for example.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: that's the way to do it, view returns an Http response, and you refresh in the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not weird as you think:

You have created an ID inside a for loop

```
 {% for days, active in zip %}
    {% if active %}
        <button id="count" type="button" class="daybutton daybutton1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{forloop.counter}}">{{forloop.counter}}</button>
```

''''

```
<button id="submit_btn" cla
```

This means multiple buttons will be created with that same ID `id="count"`.

Obviously `js` will always  return the last ID (`29` in your case*) when you do `count = $("#count").clone().html()`....

I suggest that you do not create any ID inside the loop, this will create multiple identical ids, which was supposed to be unique.

Just concatenate it will the `{{ forloop.counter }}` or `{{ instance.id }}` in case it's instances loop

or 
deal with it as `class` attributes

```
<button type="button" data-id="{{forloop.counter}}" class="daybutton daybutton1 count"....>{{forloop.counter}}</button>
```

''''

```
 <button data-id="{{forloop.counter}}" class="btn btn-link submit_btn">Send the invitation</button>
          </div>
```

and js would become:

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit_btn", function(event){
        count = $(this).closest('.clone').clone().html();
       // count = $(this).data('id'); if you just want the id;
        alert(count)
  });
```

Comment: Yep i just figured that out because of you comment!
I had the counter in the modal title before where i thought it could differ or look the opened modal up. Then i forgot to add {{ forloop.counter }} when i pasted the id to the button.

Thanks a lot! Together with `<button id="submit_btn{{forloop.counter}}" class="btn btn-link">Send the invitation</button>` in the modal it worked =)

Comment: if you had to deal with js, you need change `id` to `class` as I show in my answer

Comment: One minor thing: Like that the alert pops up multiple times - using `<button data-id="{{forloop.counter}}" class="btn btn-link submit_btn{{forloop.counter}}">Send the invitation</button>` prevents that and it still works fine.

Thanks by the way, this looks way better!